# How can I extract the coefficient of a specific variable in an equation in R?

Tags: r, string

For example, I have a string like "2 * a + 3 * b".

I already have something that checks if a certain variable exists in the expression. So for example I input b, how could I make it return the 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** If we know that the formula is linear, as in the example in the question, then we can take the derivative.

```
# inputs
s <- "2 * a + 3 * b"
var <- "b"

D(parse(text = s), var)
## [1] 3
```

**2)** If in addition there is no constant term -- there is none in the example in the question -- then we can replace all variables with 0 except for the one whose coefficient we want and replace that one with 1.  Then evaluate the expression. Assuming the same inputs we have

```
p <- parse(text = s)
L <- Map(function(x) 0, all.vars(p))   # list(a = 0, b = 0)
eval(p, replace(L, var, 1))
## [1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand you 100%. But if it is that you have a string and want to see the `d`igit(s) that occur immediately prior to `b`, then you can use `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "\\d+(?=b)")
[1] "3"
```

This works by the look-ahead `(?=b)`, which assterts that the digit(s) to be extracted must be followed by the character `b`. If you need the extracted substring in numeric format:

```
as.numeric(str_extract(x, "\\d+(?=b)"))
```

Data:

```
x <- "2a+3b"
```

Comment: What if there is a negative coefficient? E.g. `"2a-3b"`